# Convert image to binary doesn't shows white lines of a soccer field

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-thresholding

I am inspired by the following [blogpost](https://medium.com/betonchart/effective-way-to-collect-soccer-data-70ef69182eba), however I am struggling with step 2/3.
I want to creates a binary image from a gray image based on the threshold values and ultimately displaying all white lines on the image. My desired output looks as follows:

[image]

First, I want to isolate the soccer field by using colour-thresholding and morphology.

```
def isolate_field(img):
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

   # find green pitch
   light_green = np.array([40, 40, 40])
   dark_green = np.array([70, 255, 255])
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, light_green, dark_green)

   # removing small noises
   kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
   opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

   # apply mask over original frame
   return cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=opening)
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

I am happy with the results so far, but because of the large shadow I am struggling with the image-processing when I `grayscale` the picture. As a result, the binary thresholding is based on the sunny part in the upper-left corner instead of the white lines around the soccer field.

[image]

Following the methodology on the [tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding) I get the following output for the simple thresholding:
[image]

and adaptive thresholding:

[image]

and finally, Otsu's thresholding:

[image]

How can I make sure that the white lines become more visible? I was thinking about cropping the frame so I only see the field and then use a mask based on the color white. That didn't work out unfortunately.

Help is much appreciated,

Comment: You can also check whether *cv2.equalizeHist(src)* works or not. From my previous experience in MRI images, it worked perfectly fine for me in those kind of bright parts.

Comment: Without the original image, we can't experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `inRange` to also exclude saturated colors (meaning the greens). I don't have your original image, so I used your intermediate result:

[image]

The result of `inRange` is the binary image you want. I expect you can achieve better results with the original image. I used [this script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) in the image - which makes it easy to search for good HSV values.